# bitiwise exclusive or ^ with stdbool.h bool types in C and assignment

Tags: c, boolean, bitwise-operators

I have a toy program in which I use the `<stdbool.h>` library to use the type `bool`. I have a few arrays of `bool`'s, and the following commands work in a loop.

I have read online that I should not use bit-wise logic with bools. They appear to work here. Is this just luck of the draw with my compiler, or did I just misunderstand warnings about bitwise operators?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdbool.h>

#define N 5
int main(void) {
  bool a[N] = { true, true, false, false, false };
  bool b[N] = { true, false, false, true, false };

  /* to count how many pairs are opposite */
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){ count += (a[i] ^ b[i]); } 
  printf(" # pairs opposite: %i\n", count);

  /* flip the values of a */
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){ 
        a[i] = (a[i] ^ true);
        printf(" %i", a[i]);
  } 
  printf("\n");

  /* flip only the value of a that are true in b */
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){ 
        a[i] = (a[i] ^ b[i]);
        printf(" %i", a[i]);
  } 
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps what you read was talking about the `int` type used as a boolean, where `0` is false and any other value is true, and so bitwise XOR might not do what you expect.

Comment: Don't use bitwise logic with bools as they say. In your case it is working as both operands are `bool`s, which is ensuring they can only have values of `0` and `1`, so there is no problem. But if you start using some `ints` which are considered `true` when have *any* non-zero value, you might run into troubles.

Comment: To flip the values of `a`, consider `a[i] = !a[i];`.  Code for clarity.

Comment: Note: `a[i] = (a[i] ^ b[i]);` is like `a[i] = a[i] != b[i];`.  Uncertain which is more clear.

Comment: @chux, thanks the a[i] = ~a[i] is much more clear. I just wanted to get the battery of examples where the bitwise operators were working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C the values for `true` and `false` are `1` and `0` respectively. So that will work fine.

*However* you have to remember that everything non-zero is "true". So unless you have `true` or `1`, any other "true" value is not going to do what you expect using bitwise operations.

Example: Both `2` and `1` are "true", but `2 & 1` will *not* be "true".

Answer (score 0):

> I have read online that I should not use bit-wise logic with bools.
>   They appear to work here. Is this just luck of the draw with my
>   compiler, or did I just misunderstand warnings about bitwise
>   operators?

stdbool's `bool` is an alias for the standard `_Bool` type, which the standard declares to be among the standard unsigned integer types.  As a result, `_Bool` values are valid operands for the bitwise operators, and bitwise operations involving them have well-defined results.  Moreover, when any scalar value is converted to type `_Bool`, the result is either 0 or 1, depending on whether the original value compares equal to 0.

Thus, if you thought the warnings were telling you that a compiler might reject your particular example code, or that the resulting program might behave differently than if you used, say, `unsigned int` in place of `_Bool`, then yes, you did misunderstand the warnings.

As others have already remarked, this is more about the boolean interpretation of *non*-`_Bool`s than about bitwise operations on `_Bool`s.  Specifically, the boolean interpretation of the result of a bitwise operation in which at least one of the operands is a non-`_Bool` is not necessarily the same as the result of the corresponding logical operation.